# Search File inside a folder using wild card

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, fileinfo

I try to search a file using wild card.My code is:

```
          string  SearchQuery ='';
           List<ATTFile> lstFiles = new List<ATTFile>();
            if (Directory.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FilePath);//File PAth is not a problem.

              foreach (FileInfo file in dirInfo.GetFiles(SearchQuery + "?"))//Want help here  
              {

                    ATTFile obj = new ATTFile();
                    obj.FileName = file.Name;
                    obj.Folder = file.Directory.ToString();
                    obj.Size = int.Parse(file.Length.ToString());
                    obj.Extension = file.Extension;
                    lstFiles.Add(obj);

                }


            }
```

Code Works if I give full file name.
For Example:
Inside a directory I have following files.

```
and.jpg
asp.jpg
bb.jpg
cc.jpg
```

Using above code if I give full file name its work means `SearchQuery ="and.jpg"`.Its work.But If I give `SearchQuery ="a"` I want a result

```
and.jpg
asp.jpg
```

Starts all files with `a`.Is it possible using wild card inside  `GetFiles(SearchQuery + "?")`.Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx) that takes the search pattern:

```
String fileNamePart = "a";
String fileExtension= ".jpg";
String searchPattern = String.Format("{0}*{1}", fileNamePart, fileExtension);
dirInfo.GetFiles(searchPattern)
```

If you want all in one query, you can also use LINQ:

```
lstFiles = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles(searchPattern)
                  .Select(file => new ATTFile(){
                      FileName = file.Name;
                      Folder = file.Directory.ToString();
                      Size = int.Parse(file.Length.ToString());
                      Extension = file.Extension;
                  }).ToList();
```

Note that i'm using [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574.aspx) here since it can be more resource-efficient when you are working with many files and directories.

Answer (score 6):

Use [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx), you can specify wild card with it

```
* - Zero or more characters.

? - Exactly one character.
```

You can try:

```
dirInfo.GetFiles("a*");
```

instead of `?` you may use `*` in your query to get files which starts with `searchquery` and ends with any other characters.